# How to set web.xml configs in intelliJ embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to test the below session time-out property in the IntelliJ embedded Tomcat server. The below config is captured from the QA server. Somebody could you help me set up this property in IntelliJ?

web.xml

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Check the path to the used Tomcat by the IDE under `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Application Server` Try to add `session-timeout` under conf/web.xml of this Tomcat installation